# File[] to String[]

Tags: java, android, arrays

The title is basically all there is too it. I have an array of file objects...

```
File[] myFiles = myDirectory.listFiles();
```

And I want to convert it to an array of strings. (String[])

Comment: Should the strings contain the filenames or the contents? Assuming contents, are the files all guaranteed to contain only text (no binary stuff)?

Comment: And how should `File` be converted to a `String`?

Comment: People will be able to help you much more effectively if you give more detail in your questions.  It's not enough to say "The title is basically all there is too it" when there are multiple ways of interpreting the question.

Comment: -1 - for assuming that we can read your mind.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that it's the file paths you want, just create a String array of the same size, and iterate through the arrays getting the file paths and putting them in the String array:

```
String[] myStrings = new String[myFiles.length()];
for( int i = 0; i < myFiles.length(); i++ )
{
    myStrings[i] = myFiles[i].getPath();
}
```

Same for file names or whatever, just call the method for the string you want. I haven't written Java for a while, so the syntax might be slightly off, but that should give you the idea.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention the file paths is what I want. This worked though!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the file names, just use

```
String[] myFileNames = myDirectory.list();
```

It does the same thing as listFiles but instead of returning File objects it returns Strings[] of the file/directory names.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW here's a Scala way to do it:

```
val myStrings = myFiles.map(_.getPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the contents of the files as strings (which could be a very bad idea if you have enormous files), you can use the snippet to read the File to a string: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1335

Then combine that with Travis' answer to see how you would iterate over the files, call the function, and save the contents of the file to a string.